# Lidar data is reflected 180 degrees

Tags: ros, ros2, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone I use Slamtec S1 lidar in conjunction with Jetson Nano running Ubuntu 18 and ROS2 Eloquent. I'm using the [sllidar_ros2 package](https://github.com/Slamtec/sllidar_ros2) and everything looks great. But when I added lidar to my urdf file, in rviz2 I see that lidar data is displayed the other way around. I also have ZED 2, with which I get an IMU, it is also added to urdf and thanks to it my robot is moving in the right direction. However, I don't understand what is wrong with lidar, how can I turn it?

Here is a part of the urdf description with lidar, it is located in the front part of the robot, along with ZED2. Unfortunately, I can't attach files yet, but rviz2 shows as if there is a wall in front of my robot's face and a large space behind, although in reality it's the opposite.

```
  <!-- Robot Lidar -->  
  <link name="laser">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.0255" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.0225" length="0.051"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="lidar_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="laser"/>
    <origin xyz="0.4425 0 0.40" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398547/lidar-data-is-reflected-180-degrees./) by [Dr.Modi](https://answers.ros.org/users/97196/dr.modi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2022-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably have not correctly specified the yaw for the fixed `lidar_joint`. For a urdf joint, the order of operation is translate then rotate. Try setting yaw to 3.14159 (radians).

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dr.Modi](https://answers.ros.org/users/97196/dr.modi/) on 2022-04-05**:
Oh, great! It works, thank you very much!